# \begin{document} ended by \end{figure} may be compatibility issue

Tags: errors

I got the following error when compiling my thesis. I am unable to add figures/images to my thesis. Below is the minimal working example. I am working with overleaf. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Extra \endgroup.
Too many }'s.
LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.
```

Below is the .tex file which reproduces the error.

```
%  $Description: Thesis
%  $Author: xxx $
%  $Date: xxx  $
%  $Revision: 0.0 $

\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage{iiit_thesis}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Taken from other %%%%%%%%%
% \usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{graphicx,caption,subcaption}
\usepackage[super]{natbib}
% \usepackage{esvect}
% \usepackage{epstopdf}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% Taken from other end %%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{latexsym}
% \usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
% \usepackage{algorithm2e}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hidelinks, colorlinks = true, citecolor=blue]{hyperref}  %hyperref still needs to be put at the end!

\graphicspath{{LaTex/figures/benchmark/}} % To include images in other directories
\long\def\symbolfootnote[#1]#2{\begingroup%
\def\thefootnote{\fnsymbol{footnote}}\footnote[#1]{#2}\endgroup}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
\onecolumn
%--------------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}

%% TITLE PAGE
% \input{titlePage.tex}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{1.5cm}
{\Large \bf Title}

\vspace*{2.75cm}
{\large Thesis proposal submitted in partial fulfillment\\}
{\large  of the requirements for the degree of \\}

\vspace*{1cm}
{\it {\large Doctor of Philosophy \\}
{\large in\\}}

\vspace*{1cm}
{\large by}

\vspace*{5mm}
{\large Name\\}
{\small \tt mail.id@domailname}


\vspace*{2.0cm}
% {\psfig{figure=iiit.eps,width=14mm}\\}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \includegraphics{iiit.eps} 
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}
{\large Center Name\\}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

It seems these is some compatibility issue.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! We can't test your document because we haven't files included in it. If error  happen on  title page, please limit code just to it so, that we can compile it.

Comment: I have edited the post and included the title page as well. do you want me to remove intro page from the post.

Comment: well, seems that I wasn't enough clear, I ask you for small, but complete document example, which contain only front page (since you claims that error happen already here). BTW, do you really need package `epsfig`. Wee also haven't private package `iiit_thesis`

Comment: I have made this into single file. Commented `iiit_thesis` and `epsfig`.

Comment: Your issue is that you have an unmatched brace on what is currently l. 49 of the example: `{\it {\large Doctor of Philosophy} \\ `. Leaving all other things equal,* you need to close it like this `{\it {\large Doctor of Philosophy} \\}`. This solves the problem.

Comment: *I'd strongly advise against leaving all other things equal. Your code contains many suboptimal solutions. Using `\\ ` to produce whitespace; the obsolete declarations `\it`, `\bf` and the like that weren't ever really parts of LaTeX...

Comment: Now that you have edited your code as I suggested and closed the unmatched brace, do you still get the error message `Too many }'s. LaTeX Error: \begin{document} ended by \end{figure}.`? If not, then the problem is solved, right? (and it was a trivial typo)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because typos in code were solved by comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem was with the tex version. It was solved when by using tex version 2019 legacy in overleaf.